# Joining several sql columns into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine some numbers and items into basically two columns. I have a table that has 7 Item columns and 7 qty columns along with a date and id field.

[image]

How can I combine them all into basically a couple of columns, even if the items repeat? Im trying to do something like this: Item1   QTY  DATE  With Item 1 perhaps repeating as many times as its in the columns.

The outcome needs to be just one column for the items and one for the qty along with the Date column next to it if possible.

Here is my current select statement

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    Item1, Qty1, Item2, Qty2, Item3, Qty3, Item4, Qty4, Item5, Qty5, 
    Item6, Qty6, Item7, Qty7, Date, ID
FROM         
    dbo.ITEMREPORT1
```

Comment: And what should be the outcome of your query?

Comment: May I ask why you want them `|`'d together? Further, why do you want `Item1` twice and `Item3` three times?

Comment: Im not wanting the | put in there, just showing a separation of the columns here. Like I said, Im not a SQL guy here, sorry.

Comment: The outcome needs to be just one column for the items and one for the qty along with the Date field next to it if possible.

Comment: These are the problems you encounter when you don't [normalize your database properly](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the multiple columns into multiple rows, you will want to unpivot the data.  If you are using SQL Server 2008+ you could implement CROSS APPLY with VALUES:

```
select c.item, c.qty, i.date
from dbo.ITEMREPORT1 i
cross apply
(
    values
    (Item1, Qty1),
    (Item2, Qty2),
    (Item3, Qty3),
    (Item4, Qty4),
    (Item5, Qty5),
    (Item6, Qty6),
    (Item7, Qty7)
) c (Item, Qty);
```

Or you can use CROSS APPLY with SELECT/UNION ALL:

```
select c.item, c.qty, i.date
from dbo.ITEMREPORT1 i
cross apply
(
    select Item1, Qty1 union all
    select Item2, Qty2 union all
    select Item3, Qty3 union all
    select Item4, Qty4 union all
    select Item5, Qty5 union all
    select Item6, Qty6 union all
    select Item7, Qty7
) c (Item, Qty);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to UNPIVOT.  Why must every answer be spoon fed nowadays?

```
select Item, Quantity from
(
  select * from [dbo].[ITEMREPORT1]
  unpivot (
    Item for ItemOriginalColumn in (Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7)
  ) b
  unpivot (
    Quantity for QuantityOriginalColumn in (Qty1, Qty2, Qty3, Qty4, Qty5, Qty6, Qty7)
  ) c
) as d
where 
RIGHT(ItemOriginalColumn,1) = RIGHT(QuantityOriginalColumn, 1)
```

For what its worth, I used the very link from my answer that was downvoted/deleted to arrive at this solution...  Enjoy.

Comment: If your answer can be covered with *it appears that you want to something* and a link, then it isn't much of an answer in my opinion (and, in fact, you could just vote to close as a duplicate in that case). If you don't want to spoonfed an answer, then at least add some substance to your post that makes it look like an answer at all. Anyway, this answer seems good enough to merit a +1.

Comment: Haha damn kids nowadays!